# Timer Block Fails To Be Got Called

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I am using a `Timer` to be called every ~16 ms with the following code:

```
timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.014, repeats: true) { _ in

    self.someQueue.sync {
          // Do stuff
    }
}
    
timer?.tolerance = 0.004
```

where `someQueue`is defined as:

```
DispatchQueue(label: "com.app.someQueue", qos: .userInteractive, attributes: .concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem, target: .global(qos: .userInteractive))
```

The problem is whenever CPU usage increases over 60%, the more it is being used the less timer is called. For example, for CPU levels around 40%, Timer is called 62 times as expected; around 60% - 35 and around 90% - 5 (on iPad Air 2019, iOS 14.2).

How can I prioritize the block of Timer so I may be sure it will be called around 60 times at a second?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You may want to use CADisplayLink instead, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/61232771/1187415

Comment: Thanks but I am having the same result; only gets called 4-5 times when CPU usage is around 90%.